For a unity 3D multiplayer game, how to spawn and despawn multiple gameobjects for specific client?
I am working on a Unity 3D multiplayer game. There are 3 gameobjects (table, chair, pen) and apart from host, I have two client - student and teacher, consider them as two roles. I know how to instantiate a prefab and sync it across clients. But if i want to spawn-despawn one or two gameobjects for client 1 and not for client 2, how can I achieve that?
private void Update()
{
    if (!IsOwner) return;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
    {
        spawnedObjectTransform = Instantiate(spawnedObjectPrefab);
        spawnedObjectTransform.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        Destroy(spawnedObjectTransform.gameObject);

    }
    Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) moveDir.z = +1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) moveDir.z = -1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) moveDir.x = -1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) moveDir.x = +1f;

    float moveSpeed = 3f;
    transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

}

Or is there any other alternative like defining roles for clients and then setting permissions in the scene based on that role and again how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Are those objects network relevant/ need server validation or only used locally without authority?
